# html body onload function need to remove and execute the same function with cookie but only first visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

this is my html page content (a part of it)

`<body onLoad="javascript:introJs().start();">
<div id="page"> 
<div id="header">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().start();" class="friends left">Link</a>
Headline
</div>`

I have implemented [introjs](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/) with my html page as shown above. but i need to automatically execute the function given on html onLoad.. but only on first visit with cookies. I have no idea about cookies. can anyone please change or create a cookie which execute the introjs automatically on first visit.

Comment: No. This is not a "do it for me" site, rather a Q&A site. You need to try this yourself, then come back if you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) like,

**SCRIPT**

```
window.onload=function(){
   if(!localstorage.getItem('intorjsInit') && localstorage.getItem('intorjsInit')!=1)
   {
      javascript:introJs().start();
   }
   else
   {
      localstorage.setItem('intorjsInit',1);
   }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<body><div id="page">.....
```